# How can I configure Eclipse PyDev so that octothorpes respects indents when commenting a line?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I wonder whether it is possible to configure Eclipse PyDev so that when using the comment function, octothorpes respects indents when commenting a line, instead of being placed at the beginning of the line.

E.g. instead of having

```
def load_features_and_labels(dataset_type):
#     number_of_processes = 12
    print('load_features_and_labels() started')
    load_features_and_labels_start_time = time.time()
```

I want:

```
def load_features_and_labels(dataset_type):
    # number_of_processes = 12
    print('load_features_and_labels() started')
    load_features_and_labels_start_time = time.time()
```

(`#     number_of_processes = 12` vs. `# number_of_processes = 12`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no such option in PyDev.

The place to look at in the PyDev code is: org.python.pydev.shared_core.actions.LineCommentAction

Ideally, implement it (adding an option to configure how that works in PyDev > Editor > Code Style > Block Comments, which in the code is org.python.pydev.editor.commentblocks.CommentBlocksPreferences) and submit a pull request for PyDev (see: http://www.pydev.org/developers.html for instructions).

If you're not up to the task, you can create a feature request in https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ (but you can see there are lots of issues to be made, so, not sure when that will gain enough priority to be done in this case).